# What is the continuous analogue of a discrete finite automaton?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, automata

To fix ideas: let $Q$ be a set of states and $\Sigma$ a set of inputs; let $\delta : Q \times \Sigma \rightarrow Q$ be a transition function. If $Q$ and $\Sigma$ are finite, $\delta$ in conjunction with an initial state $q_0$ and an accepting set $F$ specify a discrete finite automaton.

If $Q$ and $\Sigma$ are continuous, what is the analogue of a DFA called (I am guessing this is some flavor of a "hybrid system" that crops up in the electrical engineering community)? In particular, are there any nontrivial results known for "nice" $\delta$ (e.g., convex, known qualitative properties of derivatives, etc.)?

Comment: Perhaps a [dynamical system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system#Formal_definition).

Comment: State space representation of control systems. However, you can do a lot more reasoning about FAs than you can about general dynamical systems. Just existence of solutions is an issue in general, something that does not arise with FAs. Noise (in an unspecified sense) is an issue with analogue systems that has no meaning with FAs.

Comment: @user85667 the situation I discuss is more general: it does not require any structure (e.g., semigroup/monoid/what have you) on the sets involved.

Comment: @copper.hat can you elaborate? I am not assuming any system of differential equations here, and not even any differentiable structure.

Comment: @SHuntsman It really isn't more general, since from a finite automaton you can increase $Q$ to $Q'$ by adding some terminating states representing transitions in which the original automaton is not defined, and from $\delta$ define a function on $\delta':Q\times \Sigma^*\to Q$ such that $\delta'(q,w)$ is just the value of $\delta$ after transitioning through all letters of $w$. $\Sigma^*$  is a semigroup.

Comment: @user85667 I do not understand the precise intent of your construction. I also do not understand how adding terminating states doesn't do violence to the DFA-like thing. Perhaps these two failures of mine are related--if you can elaborate I would be grateful.

Comment: @SHuntsman The $\delta'$ is a dynamical system that models the automaton; how it changes along all words in $\Sigma^*$. It contains all the information of the automaton, but now the "time parameter" ranges over the semigroup $\Sigma^*$ as required. In other words, you can replace the study of DFA, by the study of their corresponding dynamical system built this way. This construction probably has a name.

Comment: Presumably by continuous you mean infinite ($\Sigma, Q$). A discrete time state space model fits your description I believe. You are asking a fairly broad question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather unclear: what do you mean by "If $Q$ and $\Sigma$ are continuous"? Anyway, the closest thing I can think of is a *topological transformation semigroup*, that is, a transformation semigroup $(Q, S)$ in which $Q$ is a topological space, $S$ is a topological semigroup and the action $Q \times S \to Q$, $(q, s) \to qs$ is continuous. This notion is used for instance in [1], but this is just the first reference I found on Google and there are certainly other sources. In a dynamical system, the definition is the same, but the semigroup is usually commutative.

[1] Haynes, Tyler. [Thickness in topological transformation semigroups](https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/1993/250861.pdf) *Internat. J. Math. Math. Sci.* **16** (1993), no. 3, 493--502.